# How to remove frame from pyplot floating axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, axes

I would like to know how to remove the frame from `floating_axes` in `matplotlib`. [I am following the `setup_axes1` function from the `matplotlib` gallery here to rotate a plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axes.html).

Code posted below.

```
def setup_axes1(fig, rect):
    """
    A simple one.
    """
    tr = Affine2D().scale(2, 1).rotate_deg(30)
    grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(
        tr, extremes=(-0.5, 3.5, 0, 4),
        grid_locator1=MaxNLocator(nbins=4),
        grid_locator2=MaxNLocator(nbins=4))
    ax1 = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, rect, grid_helper=grid_helper)
    fig.add_subplot(ax1)
    aux_ax = ax1.get_aux_axes(tr)
    return ax1, aux_ax
```

I have tried variations of the following common ways to remove the frame on either `ax1` or `aux_ax`, but none of them work.

```
# before adding subplot
for a in ax1.spines:
    ax1.spines[a].set_visible(False)

# when adding subplot
fig.add_subplot(ax1, frameon=False)

# after adding subplot
plt.axis('off')
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
```

Any help or suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a bit, I found that the axes are stored in the `ax1.axis` object. Applying `set_visible(False)` to each of its elements produced the figure shown in the matplotlib documentation without axes (no ticks either).

```
def setup_axes1(fig, rect):
    """
    A simple one.
    """
    tr = Affine2D().scale(2, 1).rotate_deg(30)

    grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(
        tr, extremes=(-0.5, 3.5, 0, 4),
        grid_locator1=MaxNLocator(nbins=4),
        grid_locator2=MaxNLocator(nbins=4))

    ax1 = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, rect, grid_helper=grid_helper)

    fig.add_subplot(ax1)

    aux_ax = ax1.get_aux_axes(tr)

    for key in ax1.axis:
        ax1.axis[key].set_visible(False)
        
    return ax1, aux_ax
```

If you want to keep the ticks, you can further play around with the objects stored in `ax1.axis`. For example, the following replacement removes only the spines, but keeps the ticks and tick labels.

```
ax1.axis[key].line.set_visible(False)
```